# Area of the triangle

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Another easy challenge for you.

### Your task

Write a program or function that takes the input, which contains 3 pairs of x- and y-coordinates and calculates the area of the triangle formed inside them. For those who can't remember how to calculate it, you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle).

#### Example:

```
1,2,4,2,3,7       # input as x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3
7.5               # output
```

See it at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B1%2C2%5D%5B4%2C2%5D%5B3%2C7%5D+Triangle)

Some considerations:

- The input will be six base 10 positive integers.
- You may assume the input is **in any reasonable format**.
- The points will always form a valid triangle.
- You can assume the input is already stored in a variable such as `t`.
- The shortest code in bytes wins!

**Edit: To avoid any confusion I've simplificated how the input should be dealt without jeopardizing any of the current codes.**

**Remember that the your program/function must output a valid area, so it can't give a negative number as output**

Comment: You say the input is 3 pairs, but then you also say it's vectors with six numbers. Do you mean these terms mathematically, or is this restricting how the data can be taken as input? Some answers are functions that take six numbers, rather than a list of six numbers -- is that OK?

Comment: Re: your edit. Does that mean that I can have an actual array of pairs (e.g., `[[1, 2], [4, 2], [3, 7]]`) in `T`?

Comment: I'm still confused. The post still says both "3 pairs" and "six ... integers". Note that removing either one would invalidate some answers.

Comment: I don't like seeing a question change after posting and answer. **But** this time I can save 2 more bytes, so it's all right

Comment: If we can take them in as three pairs, can we take them in as a multidimensional array? That is, `[1 2;4 2;3 7]` (using Julia syntax)?

Comment: Re: "points will always form a valid triangle" - can we assume the points are always ordered clockwise or withershins?

Comment: @YiminRong I didn't understood, by that it means the the points will not form a line. I seems to be unable to see how the order would matter, can you explain to me?

Comment: @AndréMuta - If the points are ordered clockwise, the area will be negative unless absolute value is used. Just saves a few bytes if you don't need to handle both clockwise and withershins.

Comment: @YiminRong The area of a triangle cannot be negative by definition. It does not matter what order the points are in.

Comment: @YiminRong There are two notions of area, signed (oriented) area and unsigned (positive) area. This problem is using unsigned area.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## CJam, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
T(f.-~(+.*:-z.5*
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AT%3B%20e%23%20Store%20input%20in%20T.%0A%0AT(f.-~(%2B.*%3A-z.5*&input=%5B%5B1%202%5D%20%5B4%202%5D%20%5B3%207%5D%5D).

#### Idea

As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates), the area of the triangle `[[0 0] [x y] [z w]]` can be calculated as `|det([[x y] [z w]])| / 2 = |xw-yz| / 2`.

For a generic triangle `[[a b] [c d] [e f]]`, we can translate its first vertex to the origin, thus obtaining the triangle `[[0 0] [c-a d-b] [e-a f-b]]`, whose area can be calculated by the above formula.

#### Code

```
T                  e# Push T.
                   e# [[a b] [c d] [e f]]
   (               e# Shift out the first pair.
                   e# [[c d] [e f]] [a b]
    f.-            e# For [c d] and [e f], perform vectorized
                   e# subtraction with [a b].
                   e# [[c-a d-b] [e-a f-b]]
       ~           e# Dump the array on the stack.
                   e# [c-a d-b] [e-a f-b]
        (+         e# Shift and append. Rotates the second array.
                   e# [c-a d-b] [f-b e-a]
          .*       e# Vectorized product.
                   e# [(c-a)(f-b) (d-b)(e-a)]
            :-     e# Reduce by subtraction.
                   e# (c-a)(f-b) - (d-b)(e-a)
              z    e# Apply absolute value.
                   e# |(c-a)(f-b) - (d-b)(e-a)|
               .5* e# Multiply by 0.5.
                   e# |(c-a)(f-b) - (d-b)(e-a)| / 2
```

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6) 42 <s>.44.</s>

**Edit** Input format changed, I can save 2 bytes

An anonymous function that take the array as a parameter and returns the calculated value.

```
(a,b,c,d,e,f)=>(a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2
```

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser.

```js
f=(a,b,c,d,e,f)=>(a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2

function test()
{
  var v=I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  I.value = v
  R.innerHTML=f(...v)
}
```

```html
<input id=I onchange="test()"><button onclick="test()">-></button><span id=R></span>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just take the values as standard parameters and save yourself 2 characters on creating the array?

Comment: @Mwr247  the challenge says `The input will be a vector with six base 10 positive integers.`

Comment: Aha. I had initially interpreted that as meaning each pair makes up a coordinate vector (such as the Wolfram example), as opposed to the input itself being limited to an array, and as such could use other formats. Makes more sense now.

Comment: @Mwr247 now you're right

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
Area@Polygon@Partition[t,2]
```

Comment: I love how this uses a Built-in and is still longer than the cjam answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the real problem is the `Partition[t,2]`, which corresponds to the `2/` in CJam. ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 32 bytes

```
abs(det(t[1:2].-t[[3 5;4 6]]))/2
```

Constructs a matrix of the appropriate terms of a cross product, uses `det` to get the resulting value, takes absolute value to deal with negatives, and then divides by 2 because it's a triangle and not a parallelogram.

Answer (score 7):

## Matlab/Octave, 26 bytes

I did not know about this built in so far=)

```matlab
polyarea(t(1:2:5),t(2:2:6))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>79</s> 88 bytes

```
float f(int[]a){return Math.abs(a[0]*(a[3]-a[5])+a[2]*(a[5]-a[1])+a[4]*(a[1]-a[3]))/2f;}
```

Just uses the basic formula, nothing special.

Edit: Forgot to take the absolute value :(

Comment: you dont need to make it runnable?

Comment: The example just shows a function call, and that's a relatively normal default here.

Comment: Per the question, *•You can assume the input is already stored in a variable such as 't'.* So, `return(t[0]*(t[3]...` should suffice, no?

Comment: @TimmyD Feels shady doing it, but it *would* bring it down to 62 bytes. *Hmmm....* I'm going to leave it as is, for now at least.

Answer (score 5):

### [Minkolang 0.8](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Minkolang), 34 bytes

```
ndndn0g-n1g-n0g-n0g-1R*1R*-$~2$:N.
```

Anyone want some egg-`n0g`?

#### Explanation

Very straightforward. Uses the formula `|(x2-x1)(y3-y1) - (x3-x1)(y2-y1)|/2`.

```
nd      x1, x1
nd      x1, x1, y1, y1
n0g-    x1, y1, y1, x2-x1
n1g-    x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1
n0g-    y1, x2-x1, y2-y1, x3-x1
n0g-    x2-x1, y2-y1, x3-x1, y3-y1
1R*     y3-y1, x2-x1, (y2-y1)(x3-x1)
1R*     (y2-y1)(x3-x1), (y3-y1)(x2-x1)
-       (y2-y1)(x3-x1) - (y3-y1)(x2-x1)
$~      |(y2-y1)(x3-x1) - (y3-y1)(x2-x1)|
2$:     |(y2-y1)(x3-x1) - (y3-y1)(x2-x1)|/2 (float division)
N.      Output as integer and quit.
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP – 68 <s>88</s> <s>89</s> bytes

Thanks to Martjin for some great pointers!

```
<?=.5*abs(($t[1]-$t[5])*($t[4]-$t[2])-($t[1]-$t[3])*($t[6]-$t[2]))?>
```

To use it, create a file `area.php` with this content, the extra line meets the *assume the data is saved in a variable `t`* part of the specs, and the ␍ at the end adds a carriage return so the output is nice and separated:

```
<?php $t = $argv; ?>
<?=.5*abs(($t[1]-$t[5])*($t[4]-$t[2])-($t[1]-$t[3])*($t[6]-$t[2]))?>
␍
```

Then provide the coordinates on the command line as `x₁ y₁ x₂ y₂ x₃ y₃`, e.g.

```
$ php area.php 1 2 4 2 3 7
7.5
```

Comment: "You can assume the input is already stored in a variable such as `t`." `$a` -> `$t`, remove `$a=$argv;` saving 9 bytes

Comment: After that, you can replace `<?php echo` with `<?=`, saving another 7 bytes

Comment: You can say that this is PHP4.1, with `register_globals=On` in your `php.ini` file (default). Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 3):

## [JayScript](https://github.com/minxomat/JayScript), 58 bytes

Declares an anonymous function:

```
function(a,b,c,d,e,f){return (a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2};
```

Example:

```
var nFunct = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){return (a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2};
print(nFunct(1,2,4,2,3,7));
```

Comment: what does g do?

Comment: @steveverrill Nothing, I'm just an idiot. Fixing...

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 45

```
->a,b,p,q,x,y{((a-x)*(q-y)-(p-x)*(b-y)).abs/2}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
KCcQ2c.asm*@hKd-@eKhd@eKtdU3 2
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KCcQ2c.asm%2a%40hKd-%40eKhd%40eKtdU3+2&input=1%2C2%2C3%2C7%2C4%2C2&debug=0)

Works by calculating abs(a*(d-f) + c*(f-b) + e*(b-d))/2 from input a,b,c,d,e,f.

Answer (score 2):

## AWK – 51 <s>42</s> bytes

AWK has no built-in `abs` so using `sqrt(x^2)` to substitute.

```
{print sqrt((($1-$5)*($4-$2)-($1-$3)*($6-$2))^2)/2}
```

Save as `area.awk` and use as `echo x₁ y₁ x₂ y₂ x₃ y₃ | awk -f area.awk`, e.g.

```
$ echo 1 2 4 2 3 7 | awk -f area.awk
7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 50 bytes

Very simple; follows the standard equation:

```python
lambda a,b,c,d,e,f:abs(a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2.
```

The other, similarly simple approaches are longer:

```python
def a(a,b,c,d,e,f):return abs(a*(d-f)+c*(f-b)+e*(b-d))/2. # 57
lambda t:abs(t[0]*(t[3]-t[5])+t[2]*(t[5]-t[1])+t[4]*(t[1]-t[3]))/2. # 67
def a(t):return abs(t[0]*(t[3]-t[5])+t[2]*(t[5]-t[1])+t[4]*(t[1]-t[3]))/2. # 74
```

Python's access to a determinate function is through [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462514/2676531).

Thanks to [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish) for 1 byte and [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for catching an error.

Comment: you can remove the `0` from `2.0` to leave `2.`

Comment: Quite true, @muddyfish, thanks!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Division works differently depending on the version...

Comment: Clarified, @mbomb007.

Comment: You need an `abs` to make the answer positive.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 77

Based on @Yimin Rong's answer, I felt I could improve upon it by a few bytes by using `list()` rather than straight `$argv` to abbreviate some variables. Also `echo` doesn't need a space if there is delimiter between echo and the thing being echoed.

`echo$variable;`, `echo(4+2);`, and `echo'some string';` are equally valid whereas `echofunction($variable)` confuses PHP.

On the other hand, I also added `abs()` to be mathematically accurate, since some combinations of vertices yielded "negative area"

```
list($t,$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f)=$argv;echo.5*abs(($a-$e)*($d-$b)-($a-$c)*($f-$b));
```

You can run it via CLI

```
php -r "list($t,$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f)=$argv;echo.5*abs(($a-$e)*($d-$b)-($a-$c)*($f-$b));" 1 2 4 2 3 7
7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 37 bytes

```R
cat(abs(det(rbind(matrix(t,2),1))/2))
```

Converts the vector of coordinates into a matrix and tacks on a row of 1's.
Calculates the determinant and divides by 2.
Returns the absolute result.  If the order was always clockwise the `abs` would not be required.

```R
> t = c(1,2,4,2,3,7)
> cat(det(rbind(matrix(t,2),1))/2)
7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 70 Bytes

```
[math]::Abs(($t[0]-$t[4])*($t[3]-$t[1])-($t[0]-$t[2])*($t[5]-$t[1]))/2
```

Uses the same standard formula as other solutions. Per the question, assumes the array is pre-populated, e.g. `$t=(1,2,4,2,3,7)`. But *ooof*, does the `$` and `[]` syntax kill this one...

Comment: Your comment about the penalty from using `$` and `[]` inspired me to try an AWK solution which, by length, is not uncompetitive!

Answer (score 1):

### [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), 52 bytes

Assumes the input is in register `t`  as: `x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3` with `x1` at the top of `t`'s stack.

```
1kLtLtsaLtsbLtdscLtltrlalclbltla-*sd-*se-*leld++2/p
```

`1 2 4 2 3 7stStStStStSt #puts coordinates into register t (closest thing dc has to variables)
1kLtLtsaLtsbLtdscLtltrlalclbltla-*sd-*se-*leld++2/p
7.5`

This uses the following formula for area:

`(x1(y2-y3) + x2(y3-y1) + x3(y1 - y2))/2`

And for a quick breakdown of the process:

- `1k Lt Lt sa Lt sb Lt d sc Lt lt r`: set decimal precision to 1 place, move parts of the stack in `t` to the main stack and move various parts of the main stack to other registers for storage (`d` duplicates the top of main stack, `r` reverses the top two elements of main stack, `L/l` move/copy from the given register to main, `s` moves top of main stack to the given register)

  Main: `y3 x3 y2 x1`

  a: `y1`, b: `x2`, c: `y2`, t: `y3`
- `la lc lb lt la`: copy the top of the stacks in registers `a`, `c`, `b`, `t`, and `a` to the main stack in that order

  Main: `y1 y3 x2 y2 y1 y3 x3 y2 x1`

  a: `y1`, b: `x2`, c: `y2`, t: `y3`
- `- * sd`: calculate `((y3-y1)*x2)` and put result in `d` (registers `a`, `b`, `c`, and `t` are no longer used so I'll drop them from the list of stacks now)

  Main: `y2 y1 y3 x3 y2 x1`

  d:`((y3-y1)*x2)`
- `- * se - *`: compute `((y1-y2)*y3)` and `((y2-x3)*x1)`; store the former in `e` and leave the latter on the main stack

  Main: `((y2-x3)*x1)`

  d:`((y3-y1)*x2)`, e:`((y1-y2)*y3)`
- `le ld + +`: copy top of register `e` and `d` to the main stack, calculate sum of top 2 stack values (pushing result back to main stack) twice

  Main: `(((y3-y1)*x2)+((y1-y2)*y3)+((y2-x3)*x1))`

  d:`((y3-y1)*x2)`, e:`((y1-y2)*y3)`
- `2 /`: push 2 onto main stack, divide 2nd values on stack by the 1st (`d` and `e` are no longer used, dropping them from list of stacks)

  Main: `(((y3-y1)*x2)+((y1-y2)*y3)+((y2-x3)*x1))/2`

Rearranging the value on the stack we can see it's equivalent to the formula at the top of this explanation: `(x1(y2-y3) + x2(y3-y1) + x3(y1 - y2))/2`

- `p`: Print top of main stack to output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
_ḢÆḊHA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4Y5Fh9se7ujycPz//3@0oY5RrE60CZg01jGPBQA)

Takes input as 3 pairs `[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]` as Jelly has no concept of variables

### How it works

This implements the method outlined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates) that [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60803/66833) uses, in that, the area of a triangle \$(0,0), (x,y), (v,w)\$ is

$$\frac12\left|\det\left[\begin{matrix}
x & y \\
v & w
\end{matrix}\right]\right|$$

and that, for an arbitrary triple of points \$(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)\$, we can translate them to form a triangle with a corner on the origin: \$(0,0),(c-a,d-b),(e-a,f-b)\$, so the area is

$$\frac12\left|\det\left[\begin{matrix}
c-a & d-b \\
e-a & f-b
\end{matrix}\right]\right|$$

```
_ḢÆḊHA - Main link. Takes [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]] on the left
 Ḣ     - Remove [a,b] and yield it
_      - Vectorised subtraction from each of [[c, d], [e, f]] which yields
         [[c-a, d-b], [e-a, f-b]]
  ÆḊ   - Determinant
    H  - Halve
     A - Absolute value
```